# How I can build Action on Google by using Dialogflow based on Basic card and linked to website?

Tags: google-assistant-sdk

I want to know that how I could build Assistant app based on basic card response linking to NASA's Apod website .It should be like app of fact image of the day.

Answer (score 0):

Good morning, Annalhq! You can use this sample code to get started with a basic card:

```
if (!conv.surface.capabilities.has('actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT')) {
  conv.ask('Sorry, try this on a screen device or select the ' +
    'phone surface in the simulator.');
  return;
}

conv.ask('This is a basic card example.');
// Create a basic card
conv.ask(new BasicCard({
  text: `This is a basic card.  Text in a basic card can include "quotes" and
  most other unicode characters including emoji .  Basic cards also support
  some markdown formatting like *emphasis* or _italics_, **strong** or
  __bold__, and ***bold itallic*** or ___strong emphasis___ as well as other
  things like line  \nbreaks`, // Note the two spaces before '\n' required for
                               // a line break to be rendered in the card.
  subtitle: 'This is a subtitle',
  title: 'Title: this is a title',
  buttons: new Button({
    title: 'This is a button',
    url: 'https://assistant.google.com/',
  }),
  image: new Image({
    url: 'https://example.com/image.png',
    alt: 'Image alternate text',
  }),
  display: 'CROPPED',
}));
```

After your card displays as intended, you can add link out suggestion chips like so:

```
if (!conv.surface.capabilities.has('actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT')) {
  conv.ask('Sorry, try this on a screen device or select the ' +
    'phone surface in the simulator.');
  return;
}

conv.ask('These are suggestion chips.');
conv.ask(new Suggestions('Suggestion Chips'));
conv.ask(new Suggestions(['suggestion 1', 'suggestion 2']));
conv.ask(new LinkOutSuggestion({
  name: 'Suggestion Link',
  url: 'https://assistant.google.com/',
}));
```

For more information, see the docs:

https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#basic_card

https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#suggestion_chips

Comment: Thanks very very much Max for helping me. I use it and it works properly. Once again thank for guiding me